# Convergence in probability: can we write $\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}>0)$ instead of $\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}>\epsilon)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given a sequence of nonnegative random variables $\{Y_{n}\}$, if for each
$\epsilon>0$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}>\epsilon)=0
$$
or
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}\leq\epsilon)=1
$$
we say $Y_{n}$ converges to 0 in probability. We denote it by $Y_{n}
\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$.

Given $Y_{n}$ nonnegative. I find that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}>0)=0$, then $Y_{n}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$. I am wondering
that if $Y_{n}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$, do we always have $\lim
_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}>0)=0$?

If not, it means that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}>0)=0$ is
stronger then convergence in probability. To achieve $\lim_{n\rightarrow
\infty}\mathrm{P}(Y_{n}>0)=0$, what are the other conditions needed given
$Y_{n}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$ and $Y_{n}\geq0$.

Comment: No, consider the deterministic sequence $Y_n=1/n$

Comment: To add on to that first comment: since it isn't true for deterministic sequences, there are basically no extra conditions we can put on $Y_n$ to achieve $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(Y_n > 0) = 0$.